# Help with Multiple Motors/Intelligent Bricks and coding/ programming/ daisy chaining

Tags: ev3, nxt, motor

[image]

I have built the accompanying robot earlier in the week. I have a challenge where the robot needs to find white/black bricks then store them on a tray and then travel over to another robot and transfer the bricks from the tray. I am an absolute novice with coding and I'm not sure where to start.

I have access to multiple EV3/NXT units. I'm thinking I might need 3? Any Help on programming, advice, hints and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Daisy chaining is straightforward. In your EV3 project, you click the little wrench in the topleft to open the project properties and enable the option "Daisy-chain mode" below the project picture. The EV3 bricks themselves need to be connected with the USB to mini-usb cables that are normally used to connect them to your computer.
After enabling the modes, the port selectors in your blocks will have layers, first layer being the EV3-brick immediately connected to your computer. 2nd layer the EV3-brick connected to that EV3 and so on up to 4 layers (4 bricks).

However, for the project you are describing, perhaps you could do with less motors and one brick would suffice:

- grabbing and lifting can be done with one motor as is is for example done in the gripp3r standard model included with the software.
- The double articulation of your claw arm might also not be necessary
- Perhaps the arm does not need to be able to rotate if the vehicle itself is maneuverable enough